# Is there a text file for startup folder?

Tags: windows, boot

If you put shortcuts on the startup folder (`shell:startup`) then they will be run at startup. However I have some programs that sometimes need to be there and sometimes not. It's quite inefficient if you have to delete them and then recopy manually. Is there a text file for that folder so that I can comment out the programs easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PowerShell script to put in the startup folder:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe'
& 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
# & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE'
# & 'D:\GitHub\Web-wrapper\Google Keep-win32-ia32\Google Keep.exe'
```

Using script will provide you more flexibility in the future.

Additional setups if you are new to PowerShell:

- **Allow PowerShell to execute unsigned scripts:** typing [`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) in the PowerShell window.
- **Create an executable shortcut in the startup folder:** by default double click on the script will open it in Notepad, not running it. Put the actual script in a location of your choice, then create a shortcut in the startup folder with the target:

  ```
  powershell.exe -command "& 'yourpath\MyScript.ps1'"
  ```

See more: [How to run a PowerShell script in folder having space in its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53332385/3416774)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no text file to manage the Windows Start Up folder.

However, there is a program called [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) from Microsoft that can help you manage start up programs.  You can check a box to enable and disable programs as necessary.